# Listening for a Custom Trigger in a Preset (that will be instantiated in the scene)

Tags: unity

I have a Preset that is listening for a Custom Event sent from the GameObject known as Magnet.

I can't set the Preset to listen for Magnet since the Preset isn't in the scene yet (it gets instantiated at Runtime).  So I have it find the GameObject with the tag Magnet (there is only one).

Problem is that I'm using Visual Scripting and the Find GameObject with Tag node has a Green arrow output...  so I have to link it to something, I believe.

Any advice on how to properly set this up?
[image]

Comment: If I move the Magnet into the Prefab folder... then I could call the Magnet prefab from inside of my Prefab.  Then I could instantiate both my main Prefab and also my Magnet prefab... and they would be able to reference each other within the scene.  Am I thinking about this correctly?

Answer (score 1):

> I have a Preset that is listening for a Custom Event sent **from** the GameObject known as Magnet.

You can find the parameter description when creating a new node. This GameObject parameter is the target object of the event rather than the source object.

[image]

> Problem is that I'm using Visual Scripting and the Find GameObject with Tag node has a Green arrow output... so I have to link it to something, I believe.

You don't have to worry about this. It's an output control port. See [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/bolt/1.4/manual/bolt-units.html).

In some cases they are useless. When a running node tries to get the output value of another node, it will give him a cache of the results if it has already run, and will run it on the spot if it has not.

Comment: Wow, how are you seeing these detailed field descriptions in the Nodes interface? Mine just says:

Target: Game Object Input
Name: String Input

Comment: Maybe we are using  different versions? Visual Scripting used to be a 3rd party plugin called bolt until it was acquired by unity (last year? ). They are basically the same thing, but during the integration process there will be some differences from the original version.

Comment: Ah ok, I'm using the latest Visual Scripting... is your screenshot from Bolt?

Comment: Yep : ) It's from Bolt